# How to execute a Linux exec file in an AWS lambda func to process 200 imgs in s3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I need to execute a Linux file who will process some images, with the next structure:

LinuxCLI -frames -keyFrames -output

The idea is that a lambda function will receive 1-400 images from an s3 bucket and passed to the CLI as a folder.
I'm using node.js and serverless framework.
I can change the CLI to accept different parameters if need.
Does it possible?

Comment: is this cli imagemagick ? If yes lambdas already have it installed, so should be possible

Comment: no is not ImageMagick , is a custom cli. But, I think will be a good starting point. Do you have a snippet code?

Answer (score 0):

On the scenario that you are using the imagemagick you can simply download the images, into the `tmp` folder and process it or by running process with node [child processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

If you want to use other cli that the lambda image does not have, there's also ways to include it in the zip of the lamdba http://nmajor.com/posts/serverless-framework-executable-binaries-aws-lambda

Notes:

- be aware of the lambdas limits of storage, 400 images depending on the images size might be a bit much at least on one execution
- tmp folder data might not have the persist between lambda executions

another references that might help :

- https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/building-your-first-serverless-app-in-node-js-with-aws-lambda-s3-api-gateway-4d87e808d9cc
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

AWS lambdas limits : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I need to process the 400 images all at once in the max scenario, could be as low as 3, I not sure if there is a way to "system mount" the s3 objects inside lambda.

Comment: as i said it will really depend on the size of your images, if this passes the storage limit you might need to think on something else than lambda, the /tmp folder only allows to 512MB if your images have a lot more than 2MB probably you will not be able to do what you want in lambdas, and probably are better with ec2 where you have more storage and more memory available

Comment: Edited with the aws lambdas limits